# How to validate duplicate data while inserting in a table

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6

I need to insert some data in sql using node JS. Before inserting data, I want to check whether there is the same data is repeated (check for duplication) or not. If the data to be inserted is already in the table, then show an error message else successful message.

**EDIT - 1**

My data are integers, all data are from the same table and I have to check three columns combination. 
For eg: 
Column 1: Department
Column 2: Class
Column 3: Section

say one section can be allowed to insert one row. if 1, 2, 3(D, C, S) is there in the table, then this same combination should not be repeated.

Comment: Sounds good, go for it. What's your question about all that?

Answer (score 0):

We need more info to know what you need witch type of data is used if its simple data
I suggest you to use unique constraint in sql for exemple if you have simple data like text or integer you can let sql check with unique constrainta an trigg error with node like E.G

```
const select = con.query("SELECT * FROM customers", function (err, result, fields) {
  if(err){//you can check error object to get just unique constraint error
   console.log('duplicate')
  }
})
```

if you have complexe data you need to select first data loop on it and make condition on nodejs